# Rest API client should stores info?

Tags: javascript, rest, web

I have a Rest API, should my JS client store the info from a response? 
For example, let's say I have an endpoint `/users/{user_id}` which returns user information(like name, email, birthday etc). When a user login into my site the client will send a GET request in above endpoint and represent those info at home page. After this the user may check order page which should show up the user orders with the username. And after all may the user want to go back in home page. So, should I keep all these info that I get from responses somewhere to show them up when needed or I should send new requests every time?

Comment: This question is not about "how this work?". And actually only you can answer this question. What _do you want_? If user data may change in one session, so yes I think you have to make request each time. If user data can't be changed in one session - you don't have to make request each time.

Comment: It depends, maybe he wants to change his email some day.
So, where I should keep these info? Into a cookie?

Comment: Why you you want to get this right now? Is this moment is a bottleneck for you at the moment? Also, so you need user info only on one page or on each page? I think it is normal to get user data each time you log on to the site. And also you need to get extended info (orders for example) on some pages.

Comment: Yes you can store this data on cookies and update this data on some events. Actually you have different data of user. First is name, username, email, password. It is data which is updated rather rear. Another data is orders, card, favorites etc. This data is updated more often. So first one is stored on the cookies and second one is stored in the state of the app (if you do not need save it from session to session)

Comment: Nice! Thank you @SharikovVladislav

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid doing the same request multiple times, you have two options:

1. Use HTTP Caching and rely on the browser to not make the request again.
2. Store it yourself in some kind of cache, as you seem to describe.

I can't answer your question on whether you *should* do this or not. If you're trying to optimize something (speed, bandwidth) and you think that by avoiding this HTTP request you can achieve this, then yea... you should do one of those things. If you have no requirement to do this and no reason to do this, then I'm not sure why you *should*.

Comment: No I don't have requirement to do something like that. You know.. it was a question about best practice more but in the end, if I can save bandwidth/speed why not doing it?

Comment: @ChristosThb because it's always a trade-off. If you spend a LOT more time making things more efficient, but you don't need the efficiency then you are wasting your time. Generally this is called premature optimization.